# HOW do I call rebuildSelectors() on the NioWorkerPool in my NioServerSocketChannelFactory instance?

Tags: netty, cpu-usage

I'm trying to figure out WHERE to call NioWorkerPool.rebuildSelectors() in 3.6.3.

After upgrading Netty from 3.5.11 to any of the 3.6.x releases, we're hitting a CPU problem as soon as we perform any communication over our Nio-based ServerSocket channelfactory.  All 200 threads in the default pool start running at about 45-55% CPU and never return - all of the stacks showing them sitting down in the select()...poll() logic.

My problem is, I don't know when I should call this, nor where it is exposed.  The NioWorkerPool is private inside the channelfactory instance.  What is the recommended way to get access to the NioWorkerPool on my ChannelFactory - assuming this is the place to make this call.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Is it easy to reproduce ? I would love to debug it with yourkit profiler...

Comment: I'm able to do it very easily and reliably in YourKit, but the repro code is not just netty code.  It occurs in our product, which is using a 3rd party graph db under the hood.  This db uses netty for some functionality that we use.  If you'd like to contact me outta band, I could skype you and we can debug this.

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a `NioServerSocketChannelFactory`, you can specify a `NioBossPool` and a `NioWorkerPool` which were created by you.  Instead of using a shortcut constructors, use the one that accepts them.  Then you already have the references to those objects and you can call them when you wish.

Please let us know if calling `rebuildSelectors()` indeed fixes your problem.  Because it's not very easy to encounter such a problem, we are very curious if our workaround helps mitigating it.

Comment: Thanks Trustin.  I've been working with Norman a bit this morning - showing him what the code is doing and have sent him some YourKit snapshots.  Hopefully with those, we can figure out what's different between 3.5.11 and 3.6.x.  I did find a possible fix, which is calling releaseExternalResources() on the client's ChannelFactory.  I am very curious, however, why we don't need to call this in 3.5.11, but only once we've crossed over the 3.6.x boundary.  Thanks